# Routing or pathfinding algorithm for multi-direction network in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, networking, tree, path-finding

I'm trying to write a routing/path finding algorithm in JavaScript for the following network which consists of nodes. Each node has rules governing whether it can serve as an entry point, exit point, and/or be traversed.

[image: Routable Network]

Given a valid entry point is selected, I need to solve the following two problems:

1. What are the valid and available exit points for the network
2. Once a valid exit point is determined and selected, what is the optimal route (nodes that need to be traversed)

Rules of the network:

1. You can only enter nodes with entry points i.e. Nodes A, B C, D, E, F, G
2. You can only exit nodes with exit points i.e. Nodes B, C, E,, F, G
3. The direction(s) of travel  is dictated by the entry node - this governs which direction you can travel and exit. .e.g. Clockwise travel and exit when entering via Node A
4. You cannot change direction once you have entered the network.

I have represented the network as an array of objects, which each object in the array representing a node on the network.

```
    var network = [{
                     id: 'A',
                     canBeEntry: true,
                     ifEntryRouteIs: 'CW',
                     isExitIfRouteIs: 'N/A',
                     neighbourCW: ['B'],
                     neighbourCCW: ['H']
                    }, {
                     id: 'B',
                     canBeEntry: true,
                     ifEntryRouteIs: 'CW&CCW',
                     isExitIfRouteIs: 'CW',
                     neighbourCW: ['C'],
                     neighbourCCW: ['A']
                    },
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    {
                     id: 'H',
                     canBeEntry: false,
                     ifEntryRouteIs: 'N/A',
                     isExitIfRouteIs: 'N/A',
                     neighbourCW: ['A'],
                     neighbourCCW: ['G']
                    }];
```

The graphs describing the valid entry/exit nodes, transitions, and weightings would be as follows:

[image: Network Graphs]

I've done a bit or research on algorithms related to pathfinding and routing such as Dijkstra's  or A* search, but they seem to be based on costs and weightings, which I don't think applies to my network.

Does anyone have any ideas or approach on how to write an algorithm in JavaScript to first determine the exit points, then the route?

The jsfiddle of what I'm attempting to implement in JavaScript is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/mkov/dgGHm/

Comment: This seems like a competition problem. Dijkstra actually works for your case, your cost is always 1

Comment: Not a competition problem. Just bit off more than I can chew on a project ;) I think I understand how Dijkstra might assist with the routing, but what about determining the valid exit point? I need to do this first so I can build the graph for the algorithm?

Comment: You need 1 algorithm to check exits points given a starting node, and another one for getting shortest route between starting node and chosen exit node. What I dont understand is `ifEntryRouteIs`: how you know the direction of starting node?

Comment: The project is related to road journey planning. Not all nodes are entry points into the network, but for nodes where we can enter, we might only be able to travel in one direction e.g. nodes A, C, G. Similarly, we might only be able to exit from some nodes in a particular direction.  I already know the valid entry and exit direction for each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to find given a starting node and the direction, the possible exits and the shortest path to them. This should work: (had to modify the original data a bit):

```
var validExitPoints =[];
    var nodes=[];
    var tree_path=[];
    nodes.push({node:entryPoint});
    visited[entryPoint]=true;
    while(!nodes.length==0){
        var node=network_obj[nodes[0].node];

        nodes.shift();
        if(canExit(node.id,dir)){
            validExitPoints.push({node:node.id,path:''});
        }
        var neighbours=getNeighbours(node.id,dir);
        for(var i=0;i<neighbours.length;i++){
            if(visited[neighbours[i]]==false){
                nodes.push({node:neighbours[i]});
                visited[neighbours[i]]=true;
                tree_path[neighbours[i]]=node.id;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thats the main code, for full code go  here:

http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/dgGHm/6/

I used Breadth-first search for this, you can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: Thanks juvian, yes I noticed errors in my data for the link I posted. I don't think it was the latest version. Updated version set to base: http://jsfiddle.net/mkov/dgGHm/

Comment: Thanks @juvian. The solution you provided looks quite good, but forces the direction to be selected. To clarify, given a starting (entry) node (travel direction not selected but needs to be determined), what are the valid exit points? When a valid entry and exit point are chosen, what is the shortest route (and nodes being traversed). B, C, E, F, G would be valid exit points for the network (considering the direction for the entry node)

Comment: So you want to choose A as entry point and calculate exit points of both directions? Once you start going clockwise, can you go counterclockwise or you have to stay always in the same direction but be?

Comment: Correct. The direction of travel and exit is dictated when you enter into the network. Direction of travel cannot change once entered. 
For example, if you enter via node A, you can only travel in the clockwise direction and exit only in the clockwise direction, but lets say you enter through node F, you can travel in either direction, and the exit node could be in either direction. 
Valid exit nodes when entering through Node A (clockwise) would be: B, E, F, and G.

Comment: Check my new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/dgGHm/8/ . If it works correctly I can explain code or make it clearer, if not please explain me a case in which its not working correctly

Comment: Not exactly, but I think you're close. As mentioned in my comments above, the available exit Nodes when entering through Node A are B, E, F, and G, and we can only travel in the clockwise direction. Node D is a transition point, and we can only enter into the network in the counter clockwise direction. Another example, if entering into the network via Node F, we can travel in either direction and exit in either direction. So valid exit Nodes when entering via Node F, (clockwise travel and exit) are G, B, E. Valid exit Nodes when entering via Node F (counter-clockwise travel and exit) are C.

Comment: @Mkov that might be true for your drawing, but from the data you used on your fiddle my answer is working fine. In your fiddle B is not an exit. Update data correctly and it will work fine

Comment: Great, you can mark it as correct answer then ;). Good luck with your proyect

Comment: thanks for that. Sorry I think I had too many fiddles going and forgot to check for old incorrect data. Yes working perfectly! 
http://jsfiddle.net/mkov/dgGHm/9/

Just trying to step through the code to understand how it works. I have a  question, if you enter through Node B, and exit through Node F, how do you decide to travel in the clockwise direction? Do you choose the path with the lower cost (i.e. nodes traversed?). 
Also would you recommend that I restructure my network data structure to use key value pairs instead of an array of objects?

Comment: Well, its easier to access as a key value object. I had to make a little workaround for that, as I had already made it for 1 direction. What I did was: if the entry node can travel the 2 directions, get all the info for both directions, one for clockwise and one for counterclockwise. Then I check results for both and keep the different exit points. If I reached an exit point from both directions, I keep the shortest one

Comment: I've noticed when you're defining the network_neighbours in the for loop at the top, you loop through the neighbors for each direction for each node, but you assign 'CCW' to the  neightbourCW property. Is this a correct? I'm puzzled because the the routing/exit point calculation appears to still work correctly.

`for(var j =0;j< network[i].neightbourCW.length;j++){        network_neighbours[network[i].id][network[i].neightbourCW[j]]='CW';
    }
    for(var j =0;j< network[i].neighbourCCW.length;j++){
        network_neighbours[network[i].id][network[i].neightbourCW[j]]='CCW';
    }`

Comment: @mikov You are right, it should be CCW. However, I did not really use `network_neighbours` in the end as I was planning, if you check code I only use it to mark all nodes as not visited in visited object. So I ended up only using the key of network_neighbours (the node). So even if you change `'CW'` and `'CCW'` for `'saads'` it will keep working ;). You can even erase those 2 `for`

Answer (score 2):

I find your data structure for your network a bit complicated. You have essentially two graphs (cw and cww) that share their vertices, but not their edges and exit and entry points.

The implementation below defines separate graphs and joins these in a network of graphs. You can create lists of shortest paths for each graph with breadth-first search as Juvian proposed. Then you can combine these lists for all graphs.

The code below ist just the path-seeking without GUI and fiddle:

```
// Return an object that contains a path for each
// possible exit point
function find_exits(g, id, func) {
    var visited = {};
    var list = {};
    var v = g[id];
    var q = [[id, [id]]];

    visited[id] = true;
    if (v.exit) list[id] = [id];

    while (q.length) {
        var x = q.shift();
        var path = x[1];

        id = x[0];                
        v = g[id];

        for (var i = 0; i < v.edge.length; i++) {
            var next =  v.edge[i];
            if (next in visited) continue;

            visited[next] = true;
            if (g[next].exit) {
                list[next] = path.concat([next]);
            }
            q.push([next, path.concat([next])]);
        }
        path.pop();
    }

    return list;
}

// Combine two exit lists, choose the shorter path if there
// is an exit in both lists
function union(a, b) {
    var u = {};

    for (var x in a) u[x] = a[x];
    for (var x in b) {
        if (x in a && a[x].length < b[x].length) continue;
        u[x] = b[x];
    }
    return u;
}

var cw = {
    A: {
        entry: true,
        edge: ['B']
    },
    B: {
        entry: true,
        exit: true,
        edge: ['C']
    },
    C: {
        entry: true,
        edge: ['D']
    },
    D: {
        edge: ['E', 'F']
    },
    E: {
        exit: true
    },
    F: {
        entry: true,
        exit: true,
        edge: ['G']
    },
    G: {
        exit: true,
        edge: ['H']
    },
    H: {
        edge: ['A']
    }
};

var ccw = {
    A: {
        edge: ['H']
    },
    B: {
        entry: true,
        edge: ['A']
    },
    C: {
        exit: true,
        edge: ['B']
    },
    D: {
        entry: true,
        edge: ['C']
    },
    E: {
        entry: true,
        edge: ['D']
    },
    F: {
        entry: true,
        exit: true,
        edge: ['D']
    },
    G: {
        entry: true,
        edge: ['F']
    },
    H: {
        edge: ['G']
    }
};

// Housekeeping object for a network of several sub-graphs
var network = {
    graphs: [cw, ccw],
    traverse: function(func) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.graphs.length; i++) {
            func(this.graphs[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Ensure that every vertex has edge, exit, entry
network.traverse(function(g) {
    for (var id in g) {
        var v = g[id];

        if (!("edge" in v)) v.edge = [];
        if (!("entry" in v)) v.entry = false;
        if (!("exit" in v)) v.exit = false;
    }
});

// Actual path-seeking

var start = 'B';
var exits = {};

network.traverse(function(g) {
    if (g[start].entry) {
        exits = union(exits, find_exits(g, start));
    }
});

console.log(exits);
```

This example doesn't show which of the graphs the actual path is for, but that could be added easily, I think.

Comment: Thanks @M Oehm. Your solution works too, and restructuring the network this way makes more sense.